# Angularjs $http then is not working properly

Tags: angularjs

I get a value of "True" in my response. How come my `debugger` and `alert` and `AccessGranted()`  in the .then of my $http is not being invoked. Below is my Script:

```
app.controller("LoginController", function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.btnText = "Enter";
    $scope.message = "";

$scope.login = function() {
    $scope.btnText = "Please wait...";
    $scope.message = "We're logging you in.";

    $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: '/Login/Login',
        data: $scope.LoginUser
    }).then(function (response) {
            debugger;
            alert(response.data);
            if (response.data == "True") {
              AccessGranted();
            } else {
            $scope.message = response.data;
            $scope.btnText = "Enter";
        } 
    },
    function (error) {
        $scope.message = 'Sending error: ' + error;
    });
}

$scope.AccessGranted = function() {
    window.location.pathname("/Home/HomeIndex");
}
});
```

This is in my HomeController

```
public ActionResult HomeIndex()
{
    var am = new AuditManager();
    var auditModel = new AuditModel()
    {
        AccountId = 0,
        ActionDateTime = DateTime.Now,
        ActionName = "Home",
        ActionResult = "Redirected to Home"
    };
    am.InsertAudit(auditModel);

    return View("Index");
}
```

Please see image for the response I get.
[image]

Comment: What does your `HomeController` have to do with anything?

Comment: I did that too. Sorry for the confusion. I wasn't able to put it back. I was trying to get it to work so I tried removing and adding the .data in the reponse. With or without .data, it still couldn't invoke my alert, debugger and  AccessGranted() method.

Comment: Just to show that I am invoking something on my AccessGranted() method.

Comment: Have you bothered looking in your browser console? For one, `$scope.message` is **not** a function so `$scope.message('Sending error: ' + error)` will throw an error

Comment: Maybe its entering error block, check that

Comment: That was the first thing I did. But I do not get any errors in my console. Thanks for pointing that out. I'll edit my post. I am new to angular. Trying to study it.

Comment: What are you getting in `response` ?.. can you console it and show..

Comment: Pleas see the image I have included.

Comment: You're also missing the `$scope` prefix on `$scope.AccessGranted()`. Truthfully, the code in your question is an absolute mess and if there are no errors in your browser console, then this is not an accurate representation of your **real code**.

Comment: That is the only code I have in my controller. That's the whole thing. I didn't know that you have to put in the $scope in the AccessGranted(). Just like what I have said. I am very new to Angular. I am trying to learn this. But even if I get an error in the $scope.AccessGranted, my debugger should work right?

Comment: Can you alert only the response i.e., `alert(response);`

Comment: Response doesn't contain data I think, just alert response then you might be able to see "True"

Comment: The alert is not being invoked. also and so is the debugger;

Comment: I tried removing the .data in the response. That was the first things I tried before posting.

Comment: check the documentation for `$http` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 0):

seems like your approach is wrong

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$http({
  method: 'post',
  url: '/Login/Login',
  data: $scope.LoginUser
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
},
function (error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

And check your browser console for logs or any errors

Comment: I don't get any errors. I think my problem is on my Chrome Browser. In my Firefox my code works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the response is application/json content type, and content is json.

You can also write own httpProvider for check result from server

```
module.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
   ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to code like this instead of then so whenever there is success, The success part will be invoked.

```
 $http.get('/path/').success(function (data) {
        $scope.yourdata = data.data;
        //console.log($scope.yourdata);
    }).error(function (error){
//error part
    });
```

Comment: That's a good suggestion but the thing is I have to use the older version cause from what I have read, .success is already deprecated. Since I am starting, I would like to use the updated angular.